# Is it possible to do 2 things in if statement on java android?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have an if statement in my Android code. I want to execute multiple instructions when that if statement is true.

My Code:

```
if (a == true)
return b;
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

When I run this code, there is no error but last statement is not executed.

Comment: what do you mean by 2 things?

Comment: you only do one thing in that if block. you may want to read up on the difference of
if ( someThing) and if ( someThing ){}

Comment: the return statment should be at the end of the if statement..

Comment: Put the `return` statement last and use curly braces for your if.

Comment: It's better to use meaningful names for variables, not just ´a´ and ´b´.  All short names are good for it making code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: Yes first you have to put ur both line { } and also move return statement after button visibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run both statements when the condition is true, you must put the return statement last (otherwise the `setVisibility` call is unreachable), and surround the statements with curly braces :

```
if (a == true) {   
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: This is my actually code base on your suggestion:
if (getSkin==true)
        { 
        skinSeg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        return rgba;
        }
But when I ran it, it stops unfortunately after I press the button. and the matrix rgba didn't load.

Comment: @AnnisaKartikasari It's hard to say what went wrong when you supply so little code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use curly braces to enclose blocks of multiple statements.

```
if (a == true) {
    return b;
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Of course, this is a problem because you're returning something before doing something else, so you need

```
if (a == true) {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return b;
}
```

Personally, I always use curly braces even for single conditional statements - it helps to reduce the possibility of errors.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 issues in the code:

1. To excute multiple statements, enclose them in curly braces.
2. write return statement at the end of block, else it will just return from that line.

do it like this:

```
if (a == true) {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a == true)
{
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return b;
}
```

nothing after return will be executed. return should be called last.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `return *something*` you end your code at this moment. if you want to have some other logic in your if statement, you should place the return statement at the end of all your logic, for example:

```
if( a == true ){
   button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After an if statement, java executes only the next statement if it's true. If you want to execute more than one statement, put them in a brace enclosed block.

```
if (a)
    foo(); // this runs only if a is true
bar() // this runs regardles of a

if (a) {
    foo();
    bar(); // foo and bar run only if a is true
}
```

`return` is a keyword in java that immediately stops executing the current method and places the value returned to where it was called from.

```
public int foo() {
    return 4;
    return 5; // this will never be reached.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use blocks {} then only first statement after the if condition is executed. if you use block then code with in the block is executed and your code would look like

```
if (a == true) {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I did it for another case. But i don't know why when i used it to make button invisible or visible it's getting error. So, i prefer not use invisible button, but it will always visible. Thank you, everybody

Answer (score 0):

Block of statements in braces can be excecuted when if condition is true. Also, code after return statement is not reachable code.

```
if(condition){
 //statement1
 //statement2
 ------
 //statement-n
 return;
}
```